# Display the count of total number of records in the grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

I am trying to display the count of total number of records in the grid.
I used the below code but its not working.

Can you tell me how to fix it.

**Here is my code**

http://jsfiddle.net/cynmp0s3/

```
  var grid = $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid");
  console.log("grid" + JSON.stringify(grid));
  var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
  alert("dataSource", dataSource);

  var count = grid.dataSource.total();
  alert("count", count);


  //records on current view / page   
  var recordsOnCurrentView = dataSource.view().length;
  alert("recordsOnCurrentView", recordsOnCurrentView);

  //total records
  var totalRecords = dataSource.total();
  alert("totalRecords", totalRecords);
```

Comment: There's too many aspects to your fiddle to actually know what you're trying to get us to check. I don't know what button does what and I can't be bothered figuring it out. Try to reduce your code to just the problem.

Comment: @A.Lau hey when enter some value in first name text field and hit go...you will see the grid and for that grid it should show total number of records

Comment: Refine it. Also `console.log` is better since you don't have to continuously hit ok to get the next info.

Comment: @A.Lau hey removed the alerts and changed the if condition now if you hit go you can see the grid...now can you help me http://jsfiddle.net/320wuyyw/

Comment: @arkr you cannot access the total number of records in a datasource just after invoking a load. They take time to load. Did you consider the time that it takes to be available?

Comment: @OnaBai ca you update in the fiddle its so confusing

Comment: @arkr. If you have a problem with the grid? Why you did not recude your code to the minimum expression that still reproduces the problem? why so many lines of code, buttons, widgets...? Why is the DataSource being loaded from a string and then parsed using JSON stringify? You made it too complex. That takes us a lot of time to go through it and fix without not clearing knowing what you want to achieve. Ex. Why do you want to print (alert) the number of records? Is your DataSource remote or local? (it makes difference for the answer)

Comment: @OnaBai hey I needed other widgets too since I have other functionalities too...yeah DataSource is local for now...can you help me

Comment: You need the other functionality for reproducing the problem? Please, try using alert with only one argument (instead of "," use "+")

Answer (score 0):

Get length of datasource in **dataBound event** of grid.

```js
$("#grid1").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds1,
    height: 180,
    scrollable: {
      virtual: true
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "codeLong",
        title: "codeLong"
      },
      {
        field: "codeShort",
        title: "codeShort"
      },
      {
        field: "name",
        title: "name"
      }

    ],
    dataBound: function(e){
        alert("totalRecords "+e.sender.dataSource._data.length);
    }
  });
```